# Filter nested object and keep parents

Tags: javascript, object, filter, nested

I want to search an nested object by values of property 'name' and the result will keep its all parents.

For example,

```
const object = [
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Jack',
            },
            {
                name: 'Kevin',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'Lisa',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Gina',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Jack',
            }
        ]
    }    
]
```

If I search 'Mary', it should be return:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Mary',
    }
]
```

If I search 'Jack', it should be return:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Jack',
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Gina',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Jack',
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If I search 'Lisa', it should be return:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Jack',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'Lisa',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried some methods but I could only filter two layer. As below:

```
return object.filter(data => {
    if (data.children) {
        return data.name.includes(keyword) || data.children.find(item => item.name.includes(keyword));
    }

    return data.name.includes(keyword);
})
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Depth-first search algorithm?

Comment: What should happen if there are more than one person with the same name in the same lineage? For example, in the Lisa case, what if "Mary" was replaced with "Lisa"?

Comment: @JonathanHamel Thank you for pointing out that it is called Depth-first search! I learned a lot.

Comment: @kingkupps I'm curious too. In your example these solution would fail.

Answer (score 2):

You could build an object and if nested, check the children and create the parents, if necessary.

```js
function getObjects(array, target) {
    return array.reduce((r, { name, children = [] }) => {
        if (name === target) {
            r.push({ name });
            return r;
        }
        children = getObjects(children, target);
        if (children.length) {
            r.push({ name, children })
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}


var data = [{ name: 'Mary', children: [{ name: 'Jack' }, { name: 'Kevin', children: [{ name: 'Lisa' }] }] }, { name: 'Gina', children: [{ name: 'Jack' }] }];

console.log(getObjects(data, 'Mary'));
console.log(getObjects(data, 'Jack'));
console.log(getObjects(data, 'Lisa'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I really like your solution +1, and amazing speed

Comment: Thanks for your amazing solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a depth-first approach:

```
function searchWithParents(tree, query) {
    let results = [];
    for (const {name, children} of tree) {
        if (name === query) {
            results.push({name});
        }
        if (children) {
            const subtreeResults = searchWithParents(children, query);
            const mappedResults = subtreeResults.map(child => ({name, children: [child]}))
            results = results.concat(mappedResults);
        }
    }
    return results;
}

console.log(searchWithParents(object, 'Mary'));
console.log(searchWithParents(object, 'Jack'));
console.log(searchWithParents(object, 'Lisa'));
```

Comment: Your solution is very helpful. Thanks very much!